# How to break a counter loop in c++ when output reaches a certain value

Tags: c++, counter

I had lines of code here that essentially takes an input, then counts from 0 to that input by 2s. What I am stuck at is trying to stop the loop once the output meets that original input. for example, user inputs 4 and the output would be 0 2 4. User inputs 10 and it'll be 0 2 4 6 8 10.

When I try an if statement to break the code, the output just changes to 0

Sorry. I'm a newbie to c++

```
int main() {
    int x; 
    int y;
    cout << "Enter a value: " << endl;
    while (x >= 0) {
        cout << x << " ";
        y = (x += 2);
        if (y == x)break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `y` will ALWAYS equal `x` when it hits the `if` statement, because it always assigns the value of `x` to `y` in the line immediately above that.  So it will always exit the first time through the loop.

Comment: Come to think of it, where do you take the input you prompted the user for?

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior since `x` and `y` are uninitialized.

Comment: @user0042: And the actual `std::cin` statement to read input is also missing. I suspect that's no coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

`y == x` is always true in that condition (not considering UB on behalf of uninitialised variables), as you're assigning `x` to `y` in the statement above.

Use a `for` loop instead, it's perfect for this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= your_input; i += 2)
{
    std::cout << i << " ";
}
```

---

Flaws in your code:

- you're changing both variables
- one of them is not initialised to `0`, you don't take the input from user into another
- `x >= 0` is a pointless condition to have for the loop

Comment: Thank you! the for statement (and reminding me to use cin) actually helped a bunch. I got the outputs I wanted.